# jquery-Query builder usage

Tags: c#, jquery, query-builder

Hi I am new to jquery and I came across a product named "jquery-QueryBuilder" and please find its url below

http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/demo.html

I want to implement that in my asp.net mvc project.can any one help me to implement this or provide some useful url regarding if anyone using this

Answer (score 7):

I've just used this component with MVC.  These steps should get you started.

Include query-builder.standalone.min.js in your scripts.  NB if you put it in your BundleConfig use Bundle not ScriptBundle as the ScriptBundle Minification seems to cause an error.

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/queryBuilder").Include("~/Content/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"));
```

Next I created a QueryBuilderSettings class that holds all the settings for the control once it's serialised into JSON

```
public class QueryBuilderSettings
{
    public List<Filter> filters { get; set; }
    public bool allow_empty { get; set; }
    public int allow_groups { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public FilterType? type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public List<FilterOperators> operators { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public InputType? input { get; set; }
    public List<object> values { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterType
{
    @string, 
    @integer, 
    @double, 
    @date, 
    @time, 
    @datetime,
    @boolean
}

public enum FilterOperators
{
    equal,
    not_equal,
    @in,
    not_in,
    less,
    less_or_equal,
    greater,
    greater_or_equal,
    between,
    not_between,
    begins_with,
    not_begins_with,
    contains,
    not_contains,
    ends_with,
    not_ends_with,
    is_empty,
    is_not_empty,
    is_null,
    is_not_null
}

public enum InputType
{
    text,
    textarea,
    radio,
    checkbox,
    select
}
```

This is a cut down version to give you the idea if you need other settings then add them to this object.

Make a model object that contains a string for the settings and a string for the returned input.  In your controller you can create the settings and serialize them into JSON

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    QueryScreen query = new QueryScreen();
    QueryBuilderSettings settings = new QueryBuilderSettings();
    settings.allow_empty = true;
    settings.allow_groups = 1;
    settings.filters = new List<Models.Filter>();
    settings.filters.Add(new Models.Filter() { id = "Sku", label = "Sku", type = FilterType.@string, operators = new List<FilterOperators>() { FilterOperators.equal, FilterOperators.not_equal, FilterOperators.begins_with, FilterOperators.not_begins_with } });
    settings.filters.Add(new Models.Filter() { id = "EnglishDesc", label = "English Desc", type = FilterType.@string, operators = new List<FilterOperators>() { FilterOperators.contains, FilterOperators.not_contains } });
    query.QuerySetup = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings)

    return View(query);
}
```

Your view now needs to apply the settings to the control

```
<script>
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#builder').queryBuilder(@Html.Raw(Model.QuerySetup));
}) 

$("form").submit(function () {
        $('#Query').val(JSON.stringify($('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules', { get_flags: true }), undefined, 2));
        return true;
    })
});
</script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div id="builder"></div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetResults", "Home", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "results", LoadingElementId = "loading" }, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Query)
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go</button>
    }
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="loading"></div>
</div>
```

Also on the form submit I'm putting the JSON string into a hiddenFor string on the Model.

Then in the controller you can take this JSON string and parse it into a c# object

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GetResults(QueryScreen screen)
{
    RuleOrGroup query = (RuleOrGroup)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(screen.Query, typeof(RuleOrGroup));
     //do some stuff return a view.
}

public class RuleOrGroup
{
    //Fields if it's a group
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public List<RuleOrGroup> rules { get; set; }

    //Fields if it's a Rule
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public FilterType type { get; set; }
    public string input { get; set; }
    public FilterOperators @operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public bool IsAGroup { get { return condition != null; } }
}
```

Hope that's some use to anyone who stumbles upon this as I couldn't find any examples of using this with MVC out there.  Also be kind if it's a poorly constructed answer, it's hard to know how much to put in and what can be cut out.

Comment: Good part for the filter settings. The most difficult part is using the result, it is a dive into linq expressions (this got me started pretty well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx). Do you have an good idea how to do the linq expression filtering when input type is a radio, select or checkboxes?

Comment: @CularBytes, sorry once I had my RuleOrGroup object back I translated it into another object that produced SQL, the filter operators for those inputtypes should just be equal though?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gbegley/k2f46297/

Note the dependencies, which can be a bit of a chore to gather and make available to your users.

```
<span id="getsql">Get SQL</span>

<br/>
<br/>
<div id="queryBuilderGoesHere"></div>
<div id="sql"></div>
<script>
$("#getsql").addClass("ltblue");

var myFilters = [{
    id: 'column1',
    label: 'Column 1',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    id: 'column2',
    label: 'Column 2',
    type: 'double'
}, {
    id: 'column3',
    label: 'Column 3',
    type: 'boolean'
}];
$("#queryBuilderGoesHere").queryBuilder({
    filters: myFilters
});
$("#getsql").on('click', function () {
    var sqlob = $("#queryBuilderGoesHere").queryBuilder("getSQL", false);
    $("#sql").text(sqlob.sql);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my implementation:

QueryBuilderSettings.cs class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

[Serializable]
public class QueryBuilderSettings {  
    public List<QueryBuilderFilter> filters { get; set; }
    public List<string> plugins { get; set; }

    public QueryBuilderSettings()
    {
        this.filters = new List<QueryBuilderFilter>();
        this.plugins = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class QueryBuilderFilter
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> operators { get; set; }
    public string input { get; set; }
    //public List<object> values { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> values { get; set; }

    public QueryBuilderFilter()
    {

    }

    public QueryBuilderFilter(string id, string label, QueryBuilderDataType type, List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> ops, QueryBuilderInputType input, Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type.ToString();
        this.operators = new List<string>();
        foreach (QueryBuilderFilterOperators op in ops)
        {
            this.operators.Add(op.ToString());
        }
        this.input = input.ToString();
        this.values = values;
    }

    public static QueryBuilderDataType GetQueryBuilderDataType(string PropertyInputType)
    {
        QueryBuilderDataType QBFilterType;

        switch(PropertyInputType)
        {
            case "bool":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.boolean;
                break;
            case "DateTime":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.datetime;
                break;
            case "Date":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.date;
                break;
            case "Time":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.time;
                break;
            case "double":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.@double;
                break;
            case "int":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.integer;
                break;
            case "enum_dropdown":
            case "dropdown":
            case "html":
            case "stringChar":
            case "stringLine":
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.@string;
                break;
            default:
                QBFilterType = QueryBuilderDataType.@string;
                break;
        }

        return QBFilterType;
    }

    public static QueryBuilderInputType GetQueryBuilderInputType(string PropertyType)
    {
        QueryBuilderInputType QBInputType;

        switch (PropertyType)
        {
            case "bool":
                QBInputType = QueryBuilderInputType.radio;
                break;

            case "enum":
                QBInputType = QueryBuilderInputType.select;
                break;

            case "DateTime":
            case "double":
            case "int":
            case "string":
                QBInputType = QueryBuilderInputType.text;
                break;
            default:
                QBInputType = QueryBuilderInputType.text;
                break;
        }

        return QBInputType;
    }

    public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> GetQueryBuilderFilterOperator(QueryBuilderInputType? QBInputType )
    {
        List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> QBFilterOps = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>();
        switch (QBInputType)
        {
            case QueryBuilderInputType.text:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultTextOperators;
                break;
            case QueryBuilderInputType.textarea:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultTextAreaOperators;
                break;
            case QueryBuilderInputType.radio:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultRadioOperators;
                break;
            case QueryBuilderInputType.checkbox:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultCheckBoxOperators;
                break;
            case QueryBuilderInputType.select:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultSelectOperators;
                break;
            case null:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultBlankOperators;
                break;
            default:
                QBFilterOps = DefaultAllOperators;
                break;
        }

        return QBFilterOps;
    }
```

// Some Default Operators List for convenience

```
public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultTextOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.@in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};

    public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultTextAreaOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.@in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};

public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultRadioOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};


public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultCheckBoxOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.@in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};

    public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultSelectOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};

    public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultBlankOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>();

    public static List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> DefaultAllOperators = new List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators>
{
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.@in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_in,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.less_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.greater_or_equal,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_between,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_begins_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_contains,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.not_ends_with,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_empty,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_null,
    QueryBuilderFilterOperators.is_not_null
};
}
```

//enums

```
public enum QueryBuilderDataType
{
    @string, 
    @integer, 
    @double, 
    @date, 
    @time, 
    @datetime,
    @boolean
}

public enum QueryBuilderFilterOperators
{
    equal,
    not_equal,
    @in,
    not_in,
    less,
    less_or_equal,
    greater,
    greater_or_equal,
    between,
    not_between,
    begins_with,
    not_begins_with,
    contains,
    not_contains,
    ends_with,
    not_ends_with,
    is_empty,
    is_not_empty,
    is_null,
    is_not_null
}

public enum QueryBuilderInputType
{
    text,
    textarea,
    radio,
    checkbox,
    select
}
```

WebService

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Get Query Builder Filter Option")]
    public QueryBuilderSettings GetQueryBuilderFilterOption()
    {
        string QBID;
        string QBLabel;
        string propertyInputType;
        QueryBuilderDataType QBDataType;
        List<QueryBuilderFilterOperators> QBFilterOperators;
        string propertyType;
        QueryBuilderInputType QBInputType;
        //List<object> dropdownValues = new List<object>();
        Dictionary<string, string> dropdownValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        QueryBuilderSettings settings = new QueryBuilderSettings();

        // plugins
        settings.plugins.Add("bt-tooltip-errors");
        settings.plugins.Add("not-group");
        settings.plugins.Add("sortable");

        // filters
        List<string> PropertyNames = GetPropertyList(); 

        foreach(string propertyName in PropertyNames)
        {
            QBID = propertyName;
            QBLabel = PropertyTitle[propertyName];
            propertyInputType = GetPropertyInputType(propertyName);
            QBDataType = QueryBuilderFilter.GetQueryBuilderDataType(propertyInputType);
            propertyType = GetPropertyType(propertyName);
            QBInputType = QueryBuilderFilter.GetQueryBuilderInputType(propertyType);
            QBFilterOperators = QueryBuilderFilter.GetQueryBuilderFilterOperator(QBInputType);

            dropdownValues = GetDropdownDictionary(propertyName);

            settings.filters.Add(new QueryBuilderFilter(QBID, QBLabel, QBDataType, QBFilterOperators, QBInputType, dropdownValues));
            //dropdownValues =  new List<object>();
            dropdownValues =  new Dictionary<string, string>(); //Clear the Dictionary or it will add up all dropdown from different properties
        }

        return settings;
    }
```

Calling it from webpage MyPage.cshtml

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.extendext-master/jQuery.extendext.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.query-builder/js/query-builder.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.query-builder/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>

<div class="query-builder form-inline">
        <div id="builder"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var settings=AjaxFromWebService("../../WS/YourWebService.ASMX/GetQueryBuilderFilterOption", "");

        console.log(settings); // you can see the object when you press F12 on your web browser

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#builder').queryBuilder(settings);
        })
    });

    function AjaxFromWebService(Url,JsonData){
        var returnData="";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: Url,
            data: JsonData,
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            success: function (result) {
                if(result.d){
                    returnData=result.d;
                } else {
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                BootstrapDialog.alert({message:"Ajax failed",type:BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER});
            }
        });
        return function(){
            return returnData;
        }();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How to assign validation callback function name? `validation : { callback  : CustomValidateFunction }`

Comment: @BipinBaglung maybe you can try this. for each of the "filter" in settings.filters, assign validation as follows. settings.filters[i].validation = { callback: CustomValidateFunction }
Or see demo to initialise validation together with your settings https://querybuilder.js.org/assets/demo-basic.js

Comment: I could set it from JS but wanted to know if that could be set from c# at the time of QueryBuilderFilter object creation.

Comment: Not that I know of. Let me know if that's possible!